# How to set the one section timer to the Dialog derived from CProperty sheet using VC++ 2005

Tags: visual-c++

Anyone, could you please help me in display in the One sec timer, this my context:

I derived a class from CPropertySheet. Now the thing is that I want to display the current time in the sheet. So for normal dialogs I'm using ON Timer function to set the one section timer here how can I set the one second timer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all ,

I found the Solution for the above problem. this is related to One Second timer for CProperty Sheet.

I Derived Class CReview Sheet so for that I declare a member function OnTimer

```
void CReviewSheet::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if(bTimerStatus == true)
    {
        CTime t1;
        t1=CTime::GetCurrentTime();
        m_StBar.SetPaneText(2,t1.Format("%H:%M:%S"));
        bTimerStatus = false;
    }
    else
    {
        bTimerStatus = true;
    }

    CPropertySheet::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

So this is working fine. And I am able to display the Current time in my review Sheet.